How to get the child node of Accessibility event when the app seems protected
I am trying to get the balance of the Google Pay app by using the framework of accessibility service. But when it comes to the bank balance, the service fail to get the child node. It seems that the screen is protected. However I can retrieve the element using appium.
Is there any way to retrieve using accessibility service?
I tried to set
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
in serviceconfig.xml
but nothing improved.
Minimal Reproducible example:
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    AccessibilityNodeInfo mSource = event.getSource();
    boolean ifHome = false;
    int eventType = event.getEventType();
    String pkgname = event.getPackageName() == null ? "" : event.getPackageName().toString();
    AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode = getRootInActiveWindow();
}

